# Kotlin returning kotlin.Unit in result

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    val greeting = birthdayGreeting()
    println(greeting)
}
fun birthdayGreeting(): String {
        val nameGreeting= println("Happy Birthday, Rover!")
        val ageGreeting=println("You are now 5 years old!")
        return "$nameGreeting\n$ageGreeting"
    }
```

I am a newbie in kotlin language and recently on kotlin playground when i ran this code i got the output as:

```
Happy Birthday, Rover!
You are now 5 years old!
kotlin.Unit
kotlin.Unit
```

I searched the internet where it said it happens when the function is void (Unit) but here the return type of function is string. So why does it shows kotlin.Unit

I was expecting:
Happy Birthday, Rover!
You are now 5 years old!
but i got :
Happy Birthday, Rover!
You are now 5 years old!
kotin.Unit
Kotlin.Unit

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
val x = println("hello")
println(x)
```

... then you'll get this as an output:

```
hello
kotlin.Unit
```

That's because first you print String "hello" and then you print whatever the statement `println` returned. And as `println` doesn't return anything (which in kotlins world is `kotlin.Unit`) then it prints `kotlin.Unit`.

In your case maybe what you wanted was something like this:

```
fun main() {
    val greeting = birthdayGreeting()
    println(greeting)
}
fun birthdayGreeting(): String {
    val nameGreeting = "Happy Birthday, Rover!"
    val ageGreeting = "You are now 5 years old!"
    return "$nameGreeting\n$ageGreeting"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little more detail to [Tarmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74993975/13598222), `println("Happy Birthday, Rover!")` does two things:

- prints the string to standard output (this is a *side effect*)
- returns `kotlin.Unit`

You know what it returns because of [the function signature](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html):

> `fun println(message: String)`

which is really shorthand for

```
fun println(message: String): Unit
```

Every function in Kotlin returns *something*, and `Unit` is a special type that represents no result, no value. If you don't specify a return type, that's what you get as a default (which is why it's not explicitly stated as the return type in that `println` function signature).

---

So what that means, is this:

```
val nameGreeting = println("Happy Birthday, Rover!")
```

calls `println`, which returns `Unit`, so the expression on the right side of that statement evaluates to `Unit`. So you're creating a variable called `nameGreeting`, and assigning it a value of `Unit`. The same thing happens with `ageGreeting`.

That means when you get to this line:

```
return "$nameGreeting\n$ageGreeting"
```

you're creating a string that contains the values of those variables, both of which are `Unit`. When you use objects in a template string like this, it actually calls their `toString` function - and a `Unit` represents itself as `"kotlin.Unit"`. So the final string you're returning is `"kotlin.Unit\nkotlin.Unit"`, and that's why you see that printed (on two lines, because of the line break) when you call `println` with that string.

[Like Tarmo says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74993975/13598222), when you assign those greeting variables, you need to *assign a string* to them, so that text is used when you create your final string. It doesn't seem like you should be printing those strings in that function anyway (you only want to print the full result later, right?) but if you are, you'll have to call `println` separately since it doesn't return those strings.

Comment: “Every function in Kotlin returns _something_” — To split hairs, every function _that returns_ returns something. (If a function _never_ returns normally, e.g. if it always throws an exception or shuts down the whole process, then it can be declared to return `Nothing`, a special type with no values at all. That's why Kotlin has `Unit`, to distinguish those from the more common functions that return but don't produce a useful value.)

Comment: @gidds that's fair, and it's good info to have in a comment! I didn't really want to get into that in this context (since it's more about understanding basic expressions and Unit as the default implicit return type) but what you're saying is more accurate, yeah

Comment: “What's the point of Unit?” is a question that's likely to occur to learners of Kotlin — learning about Nothing may help clarify Unit for some (e.g. me), or it may just cause further confusion for others… It's hard to judge :-)

Answer (score 0):

In `birthdayGreeting()` function you're using `println` twice.

`println` return type is `Unit`.